# Seleccionar intervalos de una columna en un DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame hecho con pandas, formado por las columnas `['x','y','z0','z','arbol']`, adjunto pantallazo de su estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

De los datos de ese DataFrame general he extraído todos aquellos cuyo valor de árbol es igual a 1 creando otro DataFrame llamado `arbol1`. Dentro de la columna `z0` de este último, quiero seleccionar los valores que están entre 0.511 y 0.530 para extraerlos a un archivo .csv.

He conseguido seleccionar los datos menores de 0.530, pero no soy capaz de establecer un intervalo, solo sé ordenar mis datos, seleccionar un valor concreto (por ej z0=0597) o los valores que están por debajo o por encima de un valor.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("0Arbolesavila4.txt",header=0,names=['x','y','z0','z','arbol'])

arbol1 = df[df.arbol == 1]

print(arbol1)
print(arbol1['z0'])
print(arbol1.sort_values(by='z0'))
print(arbol1.loc[arbol1['z0'] == 0.597])
print(arbol1[arbol1.ix[:,2] > 0.511])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias posibilidades, por ejemplo:

- Usar un un filtro booleano similar a lo que haces, pero usando el operador `&` (and):

  ```
  res =  arbol1[(arbol1['z0'] > 0.511) & (arbol1['z0'] < 0.530)]
  ```

  En tiempo de ejecución es muy eficiente, es una simple máscara booleana de NumPy, el problema es que cada subexpresión separada por el operador se evalúa primero por separado y requieren de un array boolenano temporal cada una, por lo que es agresivo con el uso de RAM, especialmente en conjuntos muy grandes de datos.
- Usar [`pandas.Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

  ```
  res = arbol1[arbol1['z0'].between(0.511, 0.530, inclusive=False)]
  ```

  Para este caso concreto es posiblemente el más eficiente genéricamente de los tres y no se pierde en legibilidad.
- Usar [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

  ```
  res = arbol1.query('0.511 < z0 < 0.530')
  ```

  Es por norma general algo más lento que las dos anteriores opciones, pero es considerablemente más flexible y en muchos casos bastante más legible. Eso si, para conjuntos de datos muy grandes no requiere los arrays temporales que la primera opción requiere (usa el paquete `numexpr`), por lo que es más eficiente en cuanto al uso de memoria comparado con la máscara booleana y `&`.

> **Nota:** no es necesario ordenar explícitamente el DataFrame por esa columna previamente en ninguno de los casos.

Un pequeño ejemplo basado en tus datos:

> ```
> >>> import io
> >>> import pandas as pd
>
> >>> table = io.StringIO('''
> ...     x        y       z0
> ... 22.99   73.089    0.529
> ... 21.78   40.149    0.512
> ... 14.45   42.215    0.540
> ... 12.12   42.144    0.503
> ... 32.55   51.423    0.521
> ... 52.21   45.412    0.509
> ... ''')
>
> >>> arbol1 = pd.read_table(table, sep="\s+")
> >>> arbol1
>        x       y     z0
> 0  22.99  73.089  0.529
> 1  21.78  40.149  0.512
> 2  14.45  42.215  0.540
> 3  12.12  42.144  0.503
> 4  32.55  51.423  0.521
> 5  52.21  45.412  0.509
>
> >>> arbol1[(arbol1['z0'] > 0.511) & (arbol1['z0'] < 0.530)] 
>        x       y     z0
> 0  22.99  73.089  0.529
> 1  21.78  40.149  0.512
> 4  32.55  51.423  0.521
>
> >>> arbol1[arbol1['z0'].between(0.511, 0.530, inclusive=False)]
>        x       y     z0
> 0  22.99  73.089  0.529
> 1  21.78  40.149  0.512
> 4  32.55  51.423  0.521
>
> >>> arbol1.query('0.511 < z0 < 0.530')
>        x       y     z0
> 0  22.99  73.089  0.529
> 1  21.78  40.149  0.512
> 4  32.55  51.423  0.521
> ```

Comment: Ya me salió!muchas gracias :)

Comment: Gracias a tu ayuda he sido capaz de seleccionar el intervalo de datos que quería para el árbol uno. Ahora estoy intentando hacer lo mismo para los 7 árboles que tengo en el DataFrame original  quería saber si puedo aplicar la misma condición a cada uno de los árboles por separado de forma iterativa, es decir seleccionar los valores de zo que estén entre 1.30 y 1.35 (en este caso) para los 7 árboles.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a aplicarlo para cada valor diferente de la columna `arbol` verdad? Si es el mismo rango para los 7 árboles simplemente aplica la opción que uses al dataframe completo en vez de a arbol1, después si quieres un dataframe para cada árbol lo creas filtrando por la columna una vez aplicado el filtro del rango.